# Return value from external action in Yii

Tags: yii

How to pass a value from external action in Yii to it's parent controller?

for example:
External action looks like:

```
<?php
 class uploadAction extends CAction
{
/**
* Runs the action.
* This method is invoked by the controller owning this action.
*/
public function run()
{
    .....

        $fileName=$result['filename'];//GETTING FILE NAME

        $this->controller->image = $fileName; // this line does not work!!  

}
  }
```

when I try to get the value of images in the parent controller, nothing return!! Any help I will appreciate.

Update:
I am using an extension to upload a file .. [eajaxupload](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eajaxupload/) .

There is a long form.. have many fields, one of them is image. I want to upload that image by Ajax before submiting the whole form. Of course after user click on create button.. the controller must take all fields plus image name to store in the db.
The view ..

```
<div class="elem">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('class'=>'inputbox grid-11-12','maxlength'=>45)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="elem">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password1'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password1',array('class'=>'inputbox grid-11-12')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'password1'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="elem">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password2'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password2',array('class'=>'inputbox grid-11-12')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'password2'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="elem">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email',array('class'=>'inputbox grid-11-12','maxlength'=>45)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="elem">
            <label for="content">User Image:</label>
        <?php $this->widget('ext.EAjaxUpload.EAjaxUpload',
            array(
            'id'=>'uploadFile',
            'config'=>array(
                   'action'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl .'/backend.php/user/upload',
                   'allowedExtensions'=>array("jpg"),//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
                   'sizeLimit'=>3*1024*1024,// maximum file size in bytes
                   'minSizeLimit'=>50*1024,// minimum file size in bytes
                   'multiple'=>false,
                   //'onComplete'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl .'/backend.php/user/saveStuff/?fn='. "js:function(id, fileName, responseJSON){ alert(fileName); }",
                   //'messages'=>array(
                   //                  'typeError'=>"{file} has invalid extension. Only {extensions} are allowed.",
                   //                  'sizeError'=>"{file} is too large, maximum file size is {sizeLimit}.",
                   //                  'minSizeError'=>"{file} is too small, minimum file size is {minSizeLimit}.",
                   //                  'emptyError'=>"{file} is empty, please select files again without it.",
                   //                  'onLeave'=>"The files are being uploaded, if you leave now the upload will be cancelled."
                   //                 ),
                   //'showMessage'=>"js:function(message){ alert(message); }"
          )
            )); ?>
        </div>
```

This is the controller ..

```
    <?php

    class UserController extends Controller
    {
/**
 * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2',     meaning
 * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
 */
public $layout='//layouts/column1';
public $image;

.......


public function actions()
{
    return array(
        'upload' => array(
        'class' => 'ext.actions.uploadAction',
        ),
        );
}

........


public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new User;
    $profile=new UserProfile;
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        $profile->attributes=$_POST['UserProfile'];

        if(!$this->saveUser($model, $profile))
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', 'Not Saved :)!');

    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'profile'=>$profile,
    ));
}

public function saveUser($model, $profile)
{
    $userValid  = $model->validate();
    $profileValid  = $profile->validate();
    $valid = $userValid && $profileValid;
    if($valid)
    {
        $model->save(false);
        $profile->user_id = $model->id;
        $profile->image = !is_null($this->image)?  $this->image : null; // name of image file which uploaded 
        $profile->save(false);

        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Saved :)!');
        $this->redirect(array('index'));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

the external action in details is:

```
 <?php
 class uploadAction extends CAction
 {
/**
* Runs the action.
* This method is invoked by the controller owning this action.
*/
public function run()
{
    Yii::import("ext.EAjaxUpload.qqFileUploader");
        // make the directory to store the pic:
        $folder=Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') .'/images/' . $this->controller->id . '/';// folder for uploaded files
        if(!is_dir($folder))
        {
           mkdir($folder);
           chmod($folder, 0755); 
           // the default implementation makes it under 777 permission, which you could possibly change 
            //recursively before deployment, but here's less of a headache in case you don't
        }

        $allowedExtensions = array("jpg");//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
        $sizeLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024;// maximum file size in bytes
        $uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
        $result = $uploader->handleUpload($folder);
        $return = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);

        $fileSize=filesize($folder.$result['filename']);//GETTING FILE SIZE
        $fileName=$result['filename'];//GETTING FILE NAME

        $this->controller->image = $fileName; // ??????

        echo $return;// it's array



}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
$this->controller->image = $fileName; // this line does not work!!  
$this->controller->renderText($this->controller->image);
```

I bet this will display the $fileName.

Where do you try to access the controllers image property?

Values are not preserved between requests.

Comment: I'm trying to upload an image using this external action, then take the image name which had uploaded to save in the database in the field image_name. That $filename I have to get its value inside the controller where I have a specific function to save in my db.
in My controller I have public variable called $image .. I hope this clear enough.

Comment: maybe you should rather call the function in your controller `$this->controller->saveStuff($fileName);` or you could implement `afterAction` method in your controller. Parhaps the logic should not be in controller but in model (google more about thin-controller-fat-model)

Comment: I tried all your suggestion without effect! I am so keen to know where the value fly :)
BTW, that action does uploading by Ajax.. I don't know if that is connected to the issue!

Comment: You have to do the upload and saving to database in same request because the file will be deleted after the upload/ajax request ends. Also controller states are not preserved between requests (use session). Cannot help you more unless you provide the full code of your controller and action.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to this using a callback.

So in my controller actions() configuration I have a line:

```
'onSuccessCallback' => 'myCallback'
```

In my action class, at the end of run() I have:

```
call_user_func( array($this->getController(),$this->onSuccessCallback), $fileName);
```

In the controller I have

```
function myCallback($fileName)
{
this->image = $fileName;
}
```

I can then access the property from the controller via

> $this->image